# the COM port of USB GSM modem is not recognized automatically

Tags: serial-port, gsm, modem, virtual-serial-port

I have a D-Link USB GSM modem and I am developing an application for it using C# `SerialPort` class and AT commands. Everything, such as sending and receiving messages, works fine. However I have a problem with modem initialization. Each time I connect the modem to a USB port I have to run modem's own connection manager program called *D-Link connection manager*. Otherwise, neither computer's device manager nor hyperterminal do not recognize it and its COM port. I believe *D-Link connection manager* creates a virtual COM port for modem. I do not want that my application depends on *D-Link connection manager* all the time. Does anybody have a suggestion so I can recognize modem's USB COM port (virtual port) automatically? I appreciate your help beforehand.

Since *D-Link connection manager* cannot be used in Linux OS, this issue will be problematic if I try to use this modem on Linux systems.

PS: This problem does not exist when I use older GSM modems with serial port connection.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Windows Device manager to see what is happening when you plug the modem in and run this connection manager?

Comment: Yes I did. When I connect the modem noting happens in Device Manager; but when I run the connection manager the modem icon plus its COM port will appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see such a virtual COM port in the device manager. I don't really know about D-Link modems, but I know that for USB connected barcode scanners (Symbol/Motorola or Datalogic), there are special virtual COM port drivers that create such a COM port so that USB connected scanners can be accessed through a COM port.

While this may not be comfortable, it is still necessary, because USB connected devices can not be accessed through COM ports by default.

Comment: The problem is that no virtual COM port is created when I connect the USB modem unless I run the connection manager program. So I think I should write a program in my application to create virtual COM port for my USB modem.

Comment: Yes, because the modem itself can not create the virtual port. This must be done by some software on the PC. Either (as for the scanners) there's a driver that detects the connected USB device and creates the virtual port automatically, or (as it seems to be the case with your modem), another piece of software creates the port.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used `com0com` to create virtual modems for FoIP (sending fax over IP). I think I should use it to create virtual COM ports too. Please check [this link](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)